# Chamar Classe com função em OnPressed "Flutter"

Tags: classes, mobile, flutter

Boa noite pessoal, sou novo estudante em "Flutter", vou tentar detalhar o máximo que conseguir, caso falhe em algum detalhe peço desculpas antecipadas.

Criei uma tela"class CadastrarProdutos" e nela apliquei uma função"onSubmit", essa função guarda os dados nas variaveis informadas no código que enviarei a seguir.

Estou tentando chamar essa classe "CadastrarProdutos", em um ícone que está em um Drawer e na HomePage, porém o mesmo está apresentando erro, aguardando o parâmetro da função, gostaria de saber como passar o parâmetro da função "onSubmit", que está dentro da classe "CadastrarProdutos".
Quem puder ajudar, agradeço desde já.

++++++Abaixo o código da classe CadastrarProdutos++++++

```
  const CadastrarProdutos({
    Key? key,
    required this.onSubmit,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final void Function(String, String, int, double) onSubmit;

  @override
  State<CadastrarProdutos> createState() => _CadastrarProdutosState();
}

class _CadastrarProdutosState extends State<CadastrarProdutos> {
  final nomeController = TextEditingController();

  final tamanhoController = TextEditingController();

  final quantidadeController = TextEditingController();

  final precoController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
            );
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFd1715d),
        title: Image.asset(
          'images/logo_kginger.png',
          height: 90,
          width: 90,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Color(0xFFf4ece3),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Cadastrar Produtos',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Color(0xFFd1715d),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
              width: 10,
            ),
            Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      controller: nomeController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Nome Produto',
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: tamanhoController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Tamanho (P M G)',
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: quantidadeController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Quantidade',
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: precoController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Valor unitário(R\$)',
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            final name = nomeController.text;
                            final tamanho = tamanhoController.text;
                            final quantidade =
                                int.tryParse(quantidadeController.text) ?? 0;
                            final preco =
                                double.tryParse(precoController.text) ?? 0.0;
                            //chamada da funcao onSubmit
                            widget.onSubmit(name, tamanho, quantidade, preco);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'Cadastrar',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFFd1715d),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

++++Abaixo segue o código da classe "HomePage", que é para chamar a classe "CadastrarProdutos"++++

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Image.asset(
          'images/logo_kginger.png',
          height: 90,
          width: 90,
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFd1715d),
        // leading: IconButton(
        //   onPressed: () {},
        //   icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
        //   color: Color(0xFFd1715d),
        // ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFd1715d),
              ),
              accountName: Text('Kahinara'),
              accountEmail: Text('Kahinara@hotmail.com'),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                child: Image.asset('images/mulher.png'),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFd1715d),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Perfil',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Perfil do Usuário'),
              leading: Image.asset(
                'images/perfil.png',
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
              ),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              autofocus: true,
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Listar Produtos',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Produtos Cadastrados'),
              leading: Image.asset(
                'images/roupas_editada.png',
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
              ),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              autofocus: true,
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ListarProdutos(
                      produtos: [],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Cadastrar Produtos',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Novo Produto'),
              leading: Image.asset(
                'images/adicionar-ficheiro_editada.png',
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
              ),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              autofocus: true,
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CadastrarProdutos(),
                );
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 310),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                color: Color(0xFFd1715d),
                iconSize: 40,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: SizedBox(
                child: TextButton(
                  autofocus: true,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Listar Produtos',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFFd1715d),
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          child: Image.asset('images/roupas_editada.png'),
                          height: 100,
                          width: 100,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ListarProdutos(
                          produtos: [],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
              child: SizedBox(
                child: TextButton(
                  autofocus: true,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Cadastrar Produtos',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFFd1715d),
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          child: Image.asset(
                              'images/adicionar-ficheiro_editada.png'),
                          height: 90,
                          width: 90,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => CadastrarProdutos),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra usar os dados quando chamar o `onSubmit` você pode fazer assim:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => CadastrarProdutos(
         onSubmit: (p0, p1, p2, p3) {},
      ),
  ),
);
```

Então cada um dos parâmetros p0, p1, p2 e p3 vai ser o que você passou na chamada do método `widget.onSubmit(name, tamanho, quantidade, preco)`

Comment: Muito obrigado @Henrique Zanferrari, deu certo :)

Comment: Que bom @pablosouza. Pode escolher minha resposta como a correta?